# Send progressive data from django view to ajax

Tags: python, django, ajax, async-await

I have a django webapp. And I'm using jquery to send a POST. With that POST, I get multiple informations from the backend. But The page need to wait until all the informations are ready and then prin all of them. I would want, as an exemple, when the first one is finished, to be displayed, and then, when the second one is done, to be displayed and so on.

That's my view:

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        is_ajax = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
        if is_ajax:
            context = {}
            
            # Update the expression if it's valid
            try:
                print('---------------------------------')
                print('POST[math-input]: {0}'.format(request.POST['math-input']))
                print('POST[time]: {0}'.format(request.POST['time']))
                data = request.POST['math-input']
                core.max_time = int(request.POST['time'])
                print('---------------------------------')
                
                context = dispatch_expression(data)
            except Exception as exc:
                # exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                # fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
                # print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
                # print("Exception: {0}".format(exc))
                
                traceback.print_exc()
                context = {'result': 'Expresie invalidă!'}
            return JsonResponse(context, status=200)
    
    template = loader.get_template('home.html')

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Basically, dispatch_expression(data) is doing all the algorithms. I can modify that function to work with yields, without any problem, but I have no idea how to send each step when it's done.

I heard about async, but any example on the internet didn't help me.
I tried StreamingHttpResponse, but also, didn't work.